# Hibernate Type Mismatch in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, type-mismatch

I am receiving the following error in a Grails 2.5.0 application using Java 7 and Tomcat 7.0.55:

```
org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.myCompany.ourPackage.Program. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.Long
```

From the following line of code:

```
review.title = Program.read(programId).title
```

`programId` is not a Long, as evidenced by the following rubber-duck debugging:

```
println "programId: ${programId}"
println "programId Type: ${programId.class}"
```

Output from code above:

```
propId: 527
propId Type: class java.lang.Integer
```

Here is the stack trace in case it helps:

```
errors.GrailsExceptionResolver TypeMismatchException occurred when
processing request: [GET] /myApp/myController/myAction - parameters:
_: 1475184570336
Provided id of the wrong type for class com.myCompany.ourPackage.Program.
Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.Long. Stacktrace follows:
org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.myCompany.ourPackage.Program. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.Long
at com.myCompany.myService$_myServiceMethod_closure4$$EPyEG2zw.doCall(myService.groovy:150)
at com.myCompany.myService$$EPyEG2zw.myServiceMethod(myService.groovy:121)
at com.myCompany.myController.myMethod(myController.groovy:92)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
at net.bull.javamelody.JspWrapper.invoke(JspWrapper.java:150)
at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:285)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:198)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:176)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:62)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It should be noted that Program is a Domain in a plugin.

Class implementation:

```
package com.myCompany.ourPackage

class Program {

    Integer program

    static mapping = {
        datasource '<datasource>'
        id name: "program", generator: "assigned"
        version false
        cache usage:'read-only'
        table name:'program'
        program column: 'program', sqlType: 'int'
    }
}
```

Where `program` is the number I'm grabbing with `programId`.

Hibernate/GORM appears to be casting `programId` to a Long. Am I correct? if so, how to avoid it?

Thanks!

Comment: please provide your POJO class implementation.

Comment: have you check the column type at database ?

Comment: Added the class description. Thanks!

Comment: I thinks the problem is that you don't need to define the property program in your class. It will generated by grails in your database. So delete that property and its mapping.

Comment: And the generated class id is by default a long

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sadly, I didn't create the table definitions and the model needs to match it. For a novel schema of my own making, I would definitely apply your logic. However, changing the field type to Long alleviates any issues in this case.